# How to check if an input number is between multiple numbers Jquery?

Tags: jquery, numbers, range, between

I have an input which asks you enter the price you paid for something

```
<input type="number" class="purchase_price">
```

Now what I need Jquery to do is then to change the value for my hidden input purchase_price_date

```
<input type="hidden" name="purchase_price_data" class="purchase_price_data" value="">
```

However I need it to check the number the user entered in to the purchas_price input box, and see where it would fall in the list:
If the item was purchased for;

250-500 then change the value of purchase_price_data to "cover up to 500"

501-751 then change the value of purchase_price_data to "cover up to 750"

751-1000 then change the value of purchase_price_data to "cover up to 1000"

I was trying something like this

```
$('input.purchase_price').focus(function () {
var $this = $(this)
t = setInterval(
function () {
    if (($this.val() < 250 || $this.val() > 1000) && $this.val().length != 0) {
        if ($this.val() < 250) {
  $("input.purchase_price_data").val("hello");
        }

   
       if ($this.val() > 250) {
 $("input.purchase_price_data").val("hello something else");
       }

if ($this.val() > 500) {
 $("input.purchase_price_data").val("hello again");
       }

    }
}, 50)
})
```

But it was working quite how I need it to and when I added the third if, then it completely went the wrong way. (I had the purchase_price_data input as not hidden when testing)

Can anyone assist please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `<` for all of your values, with `if-else-if` - then the lower-limit of the range will already have been handled by the previous `if`.

You could use `<=` eg `val<=500` if the upper limit is 500

```js
$('input.purchase_price').on("input", function() {
  var val = $(this).val() * 1;

  if (val <= 0)
    $("input.purchase_price_data").val("please enter a value");
  else if (val < 250) {
    //0-249
    $("input.purchase_price_data").val("cheapskate");
  } else if (val < 500) {
    //250-499
    $("input.purchase_price_data").val("about right");
  } else {
    //500+
    $("input.purchase_price_data").val("ooh, generous");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="purchase_price" />
<input class="purchase_price_data" />
```

An alternative would be to use an array with ranges and responses, which would make it data-driven and so more flexible.

Comment: This is great! Thank you